# How do I make an method for an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys, so I have two models in my project, grinders, and votes.

So each grinder has many votes, and votes belongs to grinder.

The votes table has 3 columns: grinder_id:integer, choice:string, and voter_ip:string

How and WHERE can I make a method for my grinders? I want to be able to do something like

```
<% @grinders.each do |grinder| %>
  <%= grinder.votes_up %>
<% end %>
```

Where do I define this?

```
def self.votes_up 
  grinder.votes.find(:all, :choice => "up").count
end
```

If that is the right way to do it, correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: i would recommend reading at least _some_ sort of ruby tutorial before diving into rails...

Comment: @Matt, I have read ruby tutorials, and books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside `app/models/grinders.rb` you should write

```
class Grinder < ActiveRecord::Base
  def votes_up
    count "choice = 'up'"
  end
end
```

Comment: This is correct code. You can't have things set up properly in your database. To veriy this, replace `grinder.votes_up` with `grinder.count "choice = 'up'"`, and you'll see a failure there too.

Comment: Honestly, I don't get it.. I believe my database is set up correctly, I added my belongs_to and has_many, ect. I don't get it.